# How can I add background color to CSS triangles?

Tags: html, css, timeline

I am trying to show events in timeline view using below code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Timeline Event</h4>
                    <p>
                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-time"></i> 11 hours ago via Twitter</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel justo eu mi scelerisque vulputate. Aliquam in metus eu lectus aliquet egestas.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Timeline Event</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel justo eu mi scelerisque vulputate. Aliquam in metus eu lectus aliquet egestas.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel justo eu mi scelerisque vulputate. Aliquam in metus eu lectus aliquet egestas.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Timeline Event</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel justo eu mi scelerisque vulputate. Aliquam in metus eu lectus aliquet egestas.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS is updated in fiddle.

I am trying to add background to popup; the background color is currently white. I tried to add background-color property, but for arrow background is not reflecting.

I tried to add background-color to this CSS:

```
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    background-color: #008000;
    border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 36%;
}
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Could anyone throw light here? Thank you!

[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/N3UJQ/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/rhLvV/)

```
.timeline-panel {
    background-color:red!important;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
    border-left:14px solid red!important;
    border-right: 0 solid red!important;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
    border-left:14px solid #fff!important;
    border-right-width: 14px!important;
    border-left-width: 0!important;
}
```

*You don't need `!important` if you ordered your rules properly and/or modified the values accordingly, but it's there so the rule is shown at the top of the page.*

Comment: Good answer, but the red color is kind of jarring :-P http://jsfiddle.net/rhLvV/3/ for the grey color the OP wants to use.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the background color of the arrow. The `li` of items on the right side has the class `.timeline-inverted`, and that is what we'll use to give different CSS to the arrow pointing left.

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3UJQ/10/)**

```
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    background-color:green;
}
.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
    border-left: 15px solid green;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
    border-left: 14px solid green;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
    border-right: 14px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you know to use `.timeline-inverted`? It's not clear to me. Or is it the contents of that element rather than the name (ex: color the inside border (inverted since default is outside border) green, with a value of 14px because that's how much it takes to fill the triangle) ?

Comment: .timeline-inverted is the a class that is applied to the `li`, which is the full wrap for each timeline entry. The triangle is applied via the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Since the triangles on the right side of the line are pointing the opposite direction, they need to have different CSS. We can target them by telling the CSS to only apply to instances of `:after` on `li`s that have the class `.timeline-inverted`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that CSS is getting used. I know that some versions of IE doesn't like/understand the parent/child operator ">"

http://forums.techguy.org/web-design-development/596886-css-operator-question.html

Even Windows Explorer preview can't handle them

Change it to:

.timeline li .timeline-panel {
  ...
}

and see if it is used.